# Hard reduction formula for integral evolving $e^{ax}$ and $\cos(\ln x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-integration

So I spent a whole day trying to do this reduction formula but didn't got it ! 
The question says find the reduction formula for $$∫ e^{2x} \cos(\ln x) \,d x$$

I've searched a lot and found [this integral](http://www.math.purdue.edu/~krotz/teaching/eaxtrigbx.pdf) which is some how close to the problem but this one have a constant derivative to the function inside the Cos integrating by parts twice can send this constant to the outside, but in my question the derivative of $\ln x$ is just another variable

Is this non-integrable function ?!

Comment: One idea : it is the real part of $$e^{2x}(\cos\ln x+i\sin\ln x)=e^{2x}x^i$$

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+e%5E%5Bax%5Dcos(ln+(bx))+dx